# Wireshark != doesn't work like it did before version 3.6

Tags: wireshark

I use the filter `ip.addr != 10.0.0.0/8 && !(ip.addr == 224.0.0.0/3)` to identify any traffic between our network and the outside (and also exclude class-D address space). This filter no longer works.

It does work if I write it as `ip && (!(ip.src == 10.0.0.0/8) || !(ip.dst == 10.0.0.0/8)) && !(ip.addr == 224.0.0.0/3)` but I need to add `ip` and explicitly consider both the source and destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ip.addr` is a multi-value field and is equivalent to `ip.src || ip.dst`

Prior to version 3.6, `ip.addr != 10.0.0.0/8` would be interpreted as `(ip.src != 10.0.0.0/8 || ip.dst != 10.0.0.0/8)`.

Version 3.6 renamed the `!=` to `~=` and changed the meaning of `!=` to now mean `!(field == value)`. This means that `ip.addr != 10.0.0.0/8`
now becomes `!(ip.addr == 10.0.0.0/8)`.

This change effectively changes the logic from an OR to AND: `!(ip.src == 10.0.0.0/8) && !(ip.dst == 10.0.0.0/8)` [boolean logic: !(A+B) = !A*!B ]

Use `~=` instead of `!=` for version 3.6 or newer.

Effective for version 4.0.0:

> The operator "~=" is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use "!==", which has the same meaning instead.

So, use:

- != (up to version 3.6)
- ~= (version 3.6 up to version 4.0)
- !== (version 4.0 or higher)